# Creating Custom Bindings for KendoUI Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am trying to enable bindings for the kendoui scheduler like described here:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom#custom-widget-binding

in this dojo for example, I try to enable binding for the selectable configuration

https://dojo.telerik.com/evUXIYOX/17

There are no errors in the console log and the scheduler runs.
In the log you can also see that in the options selectable is set to true.
The binding itself seems to work, but has no effect on the behavior of the scheduler.